# Live preview of text makes the link not change background color when hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a live preview of what the user types into a input box. The text is displayed on a div.

My code:

```
var input = $('#titleText'),
            preview = $('.title');

            input.keyup(function (e){
              preview.html(input.val());
              preview.css('padding-top', '10px');
              preview.css('padding-bottom', '10px');
              preview.css('padding-right', '15px');
              preview.css('padding-left', '15px');
              preview.css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
          });
```

The problem is that I have that div in an a href and now the link does not work(it does not change its background-color when hovered over). How can I fix this?

My div:

```
<ul class = "nav nav-list nav-stacked col-md-4 col-lg-4" id = "courseNav">
            <li class = "title" class = "active"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
            <hr style = "margin-top: -0.8px">                
            <li class = "topics" style = "margin-top: -12px"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            <li class = "topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            <li class = "topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I don't see in the code where you are changing the background color?  However, here:

```
 <li class = "title" class = "active"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
```

you should change to:

```
 <li class = "title active"><a href="#">Title</a></li>
```

because you can't have 2 class= on the tag - you have to combine the classes.

also... if you change:

```
 preview = $('.title')
```

to:

```
 preview = $('.title a')
```

the link will still be clickable.